# Difference between explicit and wildcard while creating app id

Tags: app-store, bundle-identifier, apple-developer, app-store-connect

I am new to swift i want to deploy my app to app store , while creating app id when i enter the bundle id there are two option i saw **explicit** and **wildcard** [image] but i don't know what exactly they are and what are the difference between them.

refer me some some article or tutorial so that i can find difference between them and choose the best option for my app.

avoid negative voting or vote with a reason so that I can improve question.

Comment: Kindly check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 types of Ids you can Create :

**1. Explicit ID**

- This will be the Application specific & Unique Id which you will create to target any specific Application
- It will have Unique name & will be used only to install a single Application
- Lets say if you are using Explicit Id & trying to install 1 application. Now you are using same ID & installing another application it will overwrite the old application

**2. Wild Card ID**

- Wild card Id is the commonly created debug Id which will be created for testing multiple apps.
- It will have fix prefix value like com.companyname.*
- So in place of * you can pass your any of the application name which you want to use
- So by this way you can install any number of applications using the same App Id. Its normally using for testing demo versions

**Note :**

- With wild card App Id you would not be able to test few things like Push Notifications, InApp purchases etc. For that you must have to use the Explicit ID

Hope this helps to everyone.

Comment: so what i learned from your documentation is that deploying app to app store  require explicit id . wildcard is for testing purpose.. am i right?

Comment: @NaqeebAhmed yes exactly